# jwplayer for mpd files; error code: 102630

Tags: jwplayer, mpeg-dash, widevine

I'm trying to play files mpd format but I can't. I found some websites and they use this format with the next code. I copied the code but the only thing that appears is:

> (Código de Error: 102630)

This is the whole code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" src="https://ssl.p.jwpcdn.com/player/v/8.17.1/jwpsrv.js"></script>
<script src="https://content.jwplatform.com/libraries/KB5zFt7A.js"> </script>
<script charset="utf-8" src="https://ssl.p.jwpcdn.com/player/v/8.17.1/jwplayer.core.controls.js"></script>
<script charset="utf-8" src="/https://ssl.p.jwpcdn.com/player/v/8.17.1/provider.shaka.js"></script>

<script> jwplayer.key='XSuP4qMl+9tK17QNb+4+th2Pm9AWgMO/cYH8CI0HGGr7bdjo';
</script>
 <div id="player"></div>
 <script>
        var playerInstance=jwplayer("player"); 
        playerInstance.setup( {
            playlist: [ {
            title : "MEGA TELEVISIÓN HD",
             description: "https://website.com",
             image: "logo.png",
                "sources": [ {
                    "default": false,
"file":'https://chromecast.cvattv.com.ar/live/c3eds/DiscoveryHD/SA_Live_dash_enc/DiscoveryHD.mpd',
"drm": {
                       "widevine": {
                            "url": "https://sv.tsnt.xyz/cv.php"
                       }
                   }
                   , "label": "0", "type": "mpd"
               }
               ]
           }
           ], width: "730",  height: "420", aspectratio: "16:9", autostart: false, abouttext: "Site description",        
             aboutlink: "http://webiste.com", cast: {}
           ,
         skin: {
       name: "bekle",
       active: "green",
       inactive: "orange",
       background: ""
    }
       }
       );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error code means:

> **102630** No playable sources found
>
> Either an empty playlist was requested or none of the items passed our filter for valid files.
>
> [JWPlayer errors reference](https://developer.jwplayer.com/jwplayer/docs/jw8-player-errors-reference)

Check the console and network activity if available in your browser and see if you actually get a response and what it contains.

Second, the stream uses Widevine DRM. Are you on a [supported device/browser](https://support.jwplayer.com/articles/digital-rights-management-drm-reference)?
You might need to send specific headers to the licensing server in order to get a decryption key. You're just calling a PHP script with no custom data, again check the console for more feedback if it gets to the point where it makes a license request.